# Shoenfield's approach to the metamathematics of forcing

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing, meta-math

Cohen's approach to the metamathematics of forcing (see Kunen IV.5.1, new edition) involves talking about unspecified finite subsets $\Omega, \Lambda \subset \text{ZFC}$. Apparently, this is not very "elegant". For this reason Kunen introduces Shoenfield's approach. It goes as follows:

[image: Shoenfield's approach to the metamathematics of forcing as in Kunen IV.5.1, new edition]

The meta-theoretical Theorem IV.5.1 is:

> If $\text{ZFC} + \mathfrak{c} = \aleph_7 \vdash \Xi$, where $\Xi$ is
>   an arithmetical statement, then $\text{ZFC} \vdash \Xi$.

I have several questions:

1) What is the use of introducing the symbol $F$? Can't we just add to $\Sigma$ the sentence "$C$ is countable"?

2) What is meant by "explicitly" (as underlined in red above)? How is this relevant to the argument?

3) Why is talking about unspecified finite subsets $\Omega, \Lambda \subset \text{ZFC}$ considered not "elegant"?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of adding this extra symbol is due to Feferman. You're right that we do not need $F$, in general, to claim that we have a countable transitive model.

However the goal is to give an *explicit definition* of a model, a forcing, and a generic filter, which ultimately gives us an explicit definition of a model satisfying the resulting theory. For this reason we introduce $F$ as well, so it will let us do any recursive construction canonically. Of course, we can overcome this by noting that since $M$ satisfies $V=L$, there is a canonical ordering that we can use. But since we've added symbols anyway, might as well add $F$ to simplify these arguments by a lot.

The explicit part can be seen as somehow a recursive process in which we produce this model from $M$.

Finally, the lack of elegance is quite subjective, but the idea is that instead of doing this meta-theoretic induction on arbitrarily large fragments of $\sf ZFC$, we have one concrete proof of that. Whether or not you find it "better" is your choice, but this is natural to agree with Kunen once you've used forcing a few times and wrote a few forcing proofs. Eventually you even forego the countable model, and just force over the universe. But until you've had some practice, it's hard to explain exactly why.

Comment: Why can't you directly conclude from $M = L(o(C))$ that $\varphi^{M[G]}$ for all required $\varphi$ (where $G$ is any generic filter)? Why does $G$ need to be explicit? Does "explicit" mean here that we have some formula that defines it? Also, I'm also not sure where we are relying on meta-theoretic induction on arbitrarily large fragments of $\text{ZFC}$ in the usual argument (as outlined in Kunen). Metamathematics is confusing... :)

Comment: Again, you don't *need* this to be explicit. This is an aesthetic thing. But if you want your process to be, in a certain sense, constructive, you want to minimise the appeal towards existential instantiation, and instead you want a term that identifies the object you're interested in.

Comment: Meta-mathematics *is* confusing, yes. Here's an exercise to help and clarify it: by the Reflection theorem, every finite fragment of ZFC is true in some $V_\alpha$. Why doesn't this contradict the second incompleteness theorem? (In other words, why doesn't ZFC prove its own consistency?)

Comment: Because applications of the reflection theorem are really abbreviations of assertions in the meta-theory, and there is no obvious way to get from this to the claim "ZFC proves that for every finite fragment of ZFC there is a model", which is what you would need to use the compactness theorem from within the set theory. I guess...?

Comment: I don't think I understand what constructiveness has to do with this. After all the only objects involved are ZFC proofs (right?), which finitists should be able to manipulate. Whether we use existential quantifiers inside the set theory has no bearing on this, as far as I understand it. In the same sense as that a finitist would accept that ZFC proves the existence of infinite, or even uncountable objects, without having this influence his belief in infinite objects.

Comment: I mean, the thing we are after is just a finitist proof that the consistency of ZFC implies the consistency of ZFC + $\mathfrak{c} = \aleph_7$, and it appears to me this can be done without any explicitness or even the introduction of $F$. So then I don't see what this adds? Again, to be sure: does "explicit" mean here that we have some formula that defines it?

Comment: Aesthetics. This is part of the arguments about foundations and philosophy of set theory (and mathematics).

Comment: My warmest recommendation is that you simply ignore this for now. Forget about the whole thing. In a year, when you've grokked forcing, you'll remember this and suddenly understand what it's all about. Kind of like how you'd watch The Simpsons as a child, and most of the jokes actually go over your head, but that's fine, it's colourful and funny, but then you rewatch it as an adult and realise how great that show really was.

Comment: Nice analogy. OK, maybe that's good advice. But was at least my answer to your exercise correct?

Comment: Yes, the point of the exercise is to note that "finite" and "internally finite" are not necessarily the same, so there is no internal way to find, uniformly, for each fragment the least $\alpha$ satisfying this fragment.